# How to find UTC 24 hours passed between date times in linux/bash/unix?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

- Consider two UTC time stamps given. That i want to check whether they have difference in between them is more than 24 hours

Comment: Can you rephrase that, please? I can't figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I rephrase the question . Could you please check ?

Comment: How accurate does this need to be? For example, what should the behaviour across a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) be?

Comment: @l0b0, Assume it doesn't matter unless otherwise stated.

Comment: I don't want to be accurate also ( like seconds)  .  The diff b/w two stamps should be greater than 24 hours is more than enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made it .

scan_utc_time="$(echo ${scan_utc_time} | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"

Answer (score 1):

`date --date='2000-01-01 00:00:00Z' +%s` prints the Unix timestamp value at midnight UTC, January 1 2000 as an integer number. Do this conversion for both datetimes and diff them using `$(("$second" - "$first"))` to get the number of seconds between them. Then it's a simple matter of comparing the result with the number of seconds in 24 hours, 86,400.

Comment: what exactly i was searching is  assume that  i pushed some image to aws ecr at 12:00PM today ,  so i  should n't want to run push the image until 24 hours happened